# How do I make wasd controls for a top down game in unreal engine 4.13.1

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I've been trying to make controls for a top down game in unreal engine 4 but I can't figure out how to make it and all the tutorials I've been seeing are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials are perfectly fine for 4.12 and 4.13. If you are scared of incompatibility issues just download the version that is being used in the tutorial. The differences are subtle.

To your actual question. 
I recommend you watch these videos to learn about blueprints and input.  https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Videos/Blueprints/index.html

You will learn there abouth how the camera is set up in relation to the player through a thing called CameraBoom (SpringArm) component. And that if you translate the spring arm to the top of the player you will have the third person controls and the top down view you want to achieve.

This is the completest answer I can give since you have not defined your problem enough. Watch the tutorials for blueprints and make your game!

Comment: I would advise against downloading a version just for a tut, i know why people would but for the benefit of someone new it is better and more efficient to learn how to adapt the method to the way the new version works. That being said i could agree more with your answer. short of writing and actually tutorial there isn't any other way to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when the docs or other official guides are signed for precedent version of the engine this mean that these are still the same for the newer version of the engine.

When you create a new project on UE4 you can select a Template project (c++ / blueprint) where start to develop the game. You can select one of this template to see how the controller is implemented.

Try to read the documentation  https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/Framework/Controller/PlayerController/

If you have other questions on UE4 this is the best place where to write https://forums.unrealengine.com/